# make git take changes without overwriting existing code

Tags: git, merge, rebase

Branch A is the main dev branch.
Branch B contains changes that we need to keep, but we would like to maintain B with the bug fixes applied to A going forward.

So the question is: How do we tell git to take the changes in A without overwriting everything in B with A's code?

We've tried various merge strategies as well as rebasing, all to no avail. Either B is completely overwritten with A, or no changes are taken from A at all.

Comment: What you have described as your desired result—which I will rephrase as *combining work* or *combining changes* —is what `git merge` *does*. There's one key consideration though: we have to figure out the "since when" part, because Git doesn't *store* **changes** but rather whole snapshots. So what your question is missing is the information Git will find in terms of a *merge base* commit for your two commits.

Comment: Can you give details about the "various merge strategies" which failed? (and *how* they failed)? Rebasing B on A should work fine. Merge too.

Comment: I like LeGEC's answer, if he understood your situation correctly, but there is a simpler approach to consider: if you want bug fixes from A but not features from A, could cherry picking the bug fix commits from A into B be a better approach for you?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I understood from your situation :

```
             "then on"
               v
*--*--*--*--*--x--*--*--*--a <- A
    \
     -*--*--*--b <- B
```

- branches `A` and `B` forked at some point in the past,
- there is a "then on" commit somewhere in `A`,
- and you want to have a way to integrate any changes from "then on" to `B`

Here is one way to do this :

```
*--*--*--*--*--x--*--*--*--a <- A
    \            \
     -*--*--*--b--y <- B
```

- create a merge commit on branch `B`, which doesn't change `B`, but which indicates to git that all changes *prior* to `x` should be overlooked

```
# from branch B :
git checkout B

# start merging commit `x`, but don't commit anything :
git merge --no-commit x

# discard all changes and possible conflicts :
git restore --source HEAD --staged --worktree -- .

# this 'commit' action will create a merge commit, whose content is the same as `b` :
git commit
```

You can now merge `A` from `B` :

```
git merge A
```

and only the changes from "then on" will be included.

Comment: This should be a good approach if the features from A will never be merged into B. However, if at a future point in the development cycle you want to do a full feature merge of A and B, I think Git will forever overlook the commits between the original merge base and "then on".

Comment: @joanis : yes ; actually from my understanding, that's what the OP asks for (my understanding may be wrong though :) )

Comment: yep, that was probably our issue. we finally wound up just manually copying the file tree into a whole new branch. it was a horrible hack around git, but it worked!

Answer (score 1):

1- Find the point in A's commit history from which this started: "A going forward"

2- Reset HEAD to that point

3- Create new branch from that point (let's call it C)

4- Reset HEAD of A to where it was

5- Merge B into C (and now C an "upgraded B" that is based on more forwarded A)

6- Merge C into A